# return result of query with her column name MYSQL

Tags: mysql

when I get a result from a query I get the values but I want to get the name of the column too
for example, if I get {1,4,3} its a record, I want to get
for example:
num_answer:1,num_approve:4...
is it possible to do it in the query? or I must add it after?

Comment: [You're going to need to add your code if you want more assistance with this.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) By default, a MySQL query will return the column names with the values. I suspect you may be running some sort of function/class/middleware that is currently stripping this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting returning data into json object,
Consider the following table,
emplpyees_table

```html
<table>
  <th>emp_id</th>
  <th>name</th>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>KSR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>SF</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id',emp_id,'name',name) FROM employees_table
```

You can get this result,

```
[{'id':1, 'name': 'KSR'}, {'id':2, 'name': 'SF'}]
```

Comment: Can you help me understand why it doesn't work in this case:SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id',id_question,'ques',question,'yes',count yes,'no',count no) FROM ( SELECT * FROM covid19-db.Survey data WHERE approved=1) as T; the problem Start because of the count yes and no

Comment: Using spaces in column name is not a good practice. Try again after changing the column names.